# Возведение матрицы в k-ую степень

Tags: c++, матрицы

Подскажите, каким образом реализовать возведение матрицы в степень. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Умножить матрицу на себя `n` раз.

Comment: Берём бинарное возведение в степень, реализуем. А теперь так же для матрицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, вот выдержка из моего решения, может пригодиться.

Сначала реализуем метод, который производит умножение двух матриц, применяемый в 
дальнейшем в методе involution.

```
Matrix Matrix::mul(Matrix &matrix, bool flag)
{
    Matrix matrixC(this->str, matrix.stolb);
    if (this->stolb == matrix.str) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < matrix.stolb; j++) {
                matrixC.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                for (size_t k = 0; k < this->stolb; k++)
                    matrixC.matrix[i][j] += this->matrix[i][k] * matrix.matrix[k][j];
            }
        if(!flag)
            matrix.str = this->str;
        return matrixC;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Количество столбцов первой матрицы должно быть равно числу строк второй!" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Потом метод реализующий само возведение в степень. В моем случае только не работает возведение в отрицательную степень (это можно решить путем перевода матрицы в обратную и попутного самоумножения ее столько раз сколько требует степень))) Моё же решение упрощено.

```
Matrix Matrix::involution(int n)
{
    bool flag;
    if (str == stolb)
    {
        Matrix matrixC(str, stolb);
        if (n == 0)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < str; i++)
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < stolb; j++)
                    matrixC.matrix[i][j] = 0;
                matrixC.matrix[i][i] = 1;
            }
            return matrixC;
        }
        else if (n == 1)
        {
            matrixC = *this;
        }
        else
        {
           flag = false;
            matrixC = mul(*this, flag);
            for (size_t i = 3; i <= n; i++)
                matrixC = mul(matrixC, flag);
        }
        return matrixC;
   }
    else
    {
        throw 202;
        std::cout << "Матрица не квадратная!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Удачи!)